# Monitoring memory consumption by different java objects

Tags: java, memory-management

If we have 300 classes in an application, is it possible to monitor how many instances of each class we have at a given time? Is it possible to know how much memory each instance is consuming?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally like [Yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/download/index.jsp). It has a very good UI and comes with a 30 day trial. The details are also pretty extensive.

The [online help document](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/index.jsp) in that site should help you on how to set things up for running it.

Answer (score 3):

JDK 1.6 includes a tool called [jvisualvm](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html), which allows you to view lots of information about your running Java program, including memory usage, threads, etc. You could also use a profiler to see this kind of information. The profiler in [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) looks a lot like JVisualVM.

Answer (score 1):

use [profiler4j](http://profiler4j.sourceforge.net/)  or [pmd](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)

personally i like profiler4J for its ease of use and [simple graphics](http://profiler4j.sourceforge.net/#Screenshots) :)

Answer (score 0):

use jvisualvm.exe it is part of the JDK6

Comment: Does JVisualVM show instance counts and memory size by class?  I know it shows thread activity and overall memory footprint, etc., but I didn't think it had the features the OP was looking for.

Comment: https://visualvm.dev.java.net/features.html

Take and browse heap dumps. When you need to browse contents of application memory or uncover a memory leak in your application, you'll find the built-in HeapWalker tool really handy. It can read files written in hprof format and is also able to browse heap dumps created by the JVM on an OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Java profiler, depending on which web container (if it's a web-app) you're deploying to you can try alot of different profilers: http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers

Answer (score 0):

Most profilers will give you this information.  I'm personally familiar with [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/features.html), but I expect any worthwhile profiler would let you do this.

For a more low-tech solution, you could even trigger a heap dump from your application and then look through it with an application like jhat.  The interface leaves a lot to be desired, though, and profilers would be much more comfortable to use in any non-trivial case.

Edit: [here](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/images/memory_monitor_fsb.png) is an example of the memory screen for JProfiler, and you can also investigate the [reference chain](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/images/heap_walker_references_fsb.png).